# How to check if user has checked captcha checkbox ssjs ampscript

Tags: exacttarget, ampscript

How i can check if the user has clicked the captcha checkbox and display an error if user has not checked the captcha checkbox.

Regards

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud), [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) and [ssjs](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssjs) tags.

Answer (score 1):

Since you referenced **ssjs** and **AMPScript**, I assume your question relates to Marketing Cloud landing pages (or Cloud Pages).  I'm uncertain how you captcha checkbox is implemented.  Since you did not provide a code sample.  But, I assume this is just a checkbox in an HTML form.  The
[RequestParameter()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/#RequestParameter)  **AMPScript** function will allow you to retrieve the value of the checkbox upon a form post.  The function will only return a value if the field is checked.